# Cannot use wide strings in C/C++ Visual Studio, even though it works in CodeBlocks using MinGW

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, winapi, widechar

I'm trying to use the Windows API in Visual Studio 2019. The problem is that when I'm trying to create a wide string, using something like this: `L"Hello World!"`, I get an error: *'L': identifier not found*

Then, I tried using the `TEXT()` function, which, from what I understand, is supposed to convert a string to a wide string:

```
char test[1024]; /// contains some text
SetWindowText(DMG_LABEL, TEXT(test));
```

Here I get this error: *'Ltest': undeclared identifier*

This worked on CodeBlocks using MinGW, so I don't see why it wouldn't work in VS. (Tested this in C++, but I'm pretty sure in C it's the same thing).

What exactly am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Thanks to @anastaciu , I didn't realize that I wasn't using `wchar_t`

Comment: Maybe using `wchar_t`.

Comment: Your question would be better if you showed a 10 line program that someone could test. Currently we have to guess what bug you have.

Comment: [Relevant docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Note: You misunderstand `TEXT`. It is a macro that turns a string literal into a wide character string literal (`TEXT("string)"` becomes `L"string"`) at compile time if `UNICODE` is defined. Otherwise it does nothing. It cannot transform a string at runtime. `TEXT(test)` will become `Ltext` and probably result in an odd-looking compiler error.

Comment: The TEXT macro defined in `winnt.h` is only designed to use string literals, not variables. To define unicode strings, use either `wchar_t` instead of `char` or the correlating WinAPI typedef `WCHAR`. One additional advice is that you always specify if you want to use the Ansi or Unicode version of the WinAPI function instead of the macro to prevent possible mistakes due to configuration errors.

Comment: I realized now that TEXT() is a macro (or, better said, I knew TEXT() was a macro, but for some reason it didn't click that I cannot use it without having an actual string literal

Comment: @H-005 "*This worked on CodeBlocks using MinGW*" - then there is something seriously wrong with CB/MinGW if it allows this. "*I don't see why it wouldn't work in VS*" - because it is not supposed to work, for the reason already stated (`TEXT()` only works on literals, not on variables).

Comment: @rem `TEXT` is **meant** to be used on string literals, but it still 'works' on anything, as long as neither the `UNICODE` nor `_UNICODE` preprocessor symbols are defined. Incidentally, Code::Blocks doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in Code::Blocks, because Code::Blocks sucks.

Code::Blocks still thinks, in 2021, that using codepage encoding were the proper default. As a result, the `TEXT` macro expands to nothing.

With an IDE like Visual Studio, that defaults to using Unicode, the `TEXT` macro expands to a token pasting sequence, slapping `L` to its argument, whatever that argument is. It is meant to be used with string literals, and in that case it does what one would expect. If you use it with a variable name, then, well, it still slaps an `L` in front of it.

So instead of `test`, the compiler now gets to see `Ltest`. It either uses the symbol named `Ltest`, or produces an error when it cannot find it.

> What exactly am I doing wrong?

You are using a function-like preprocessor symbol, that's meant to be used with string literals, on something that isn't a string literal.

Answer (score -3):

project properties->Advanced->Character Set = Use Unicode Character Set

or before adding <windows.h>

```
#if !defined(_UNICODE)
#define _UNICODE
#endif
#if !defined(UNICODE)
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include  <windows.h>
```

Comment: This will not change the fact that the `TEXT` macro only works with string literals.

Comment: Or that the asker simply forgot to use `wchar_t`.

Comment: Oh, great. Now you have `_UNICODE`, `UNICODE`, `_MBCS`, and `MBCS` defined. All at the same time! WHAT COULD POSSIBLY GO WRONG!?